# SymmetricDS bi-directional

Tags: database-replication, symmetricds

I try to understand if is possible:
Central: table1
On local nodes table1_1 table1_2 table1_3 table1_4 ...
I have made propagation from table1 to tables table1_1, table1_2, table1_3, table1_4...
It is working.

But now need to make opposite. E.g. in table table1_1 happen changes - change have be passed to table1 (central) and after that to table1_2, table1_3 ....

Is it possible or not?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

As wrote in documentation

> "A node will always push and pull data
>   to other node groups according to the
>   node group link configuration. A node
>   can only pull and push data to other
>   nodes that are represented node table
>   in its database and having
>   sync_enabled = 1."

So need configure table `NODE_GROUP_LINK` for each tier.